Sponsoring the deployment of a Safe without the need to create another transaction
I am sponsoring the deployment of a Safe using the Safe4337Pack and Pimlico.
I am doing this:
const safe4337Pack = await Safe4337Pack.init({
    provider: RPC_URL,
    signer: "0x_PrivateKey",
    bundlerUrl: BUNDLER_URL,
    options: {
        owners,
        threshold
    },
    paymasterOptions: {
        isSponsored: true,
        paymasterUrl: paymasterUrl,
    }
});

And then when I do this,
const isSafeDeployed = await safe4337Pack.protocolKit.isSafeDeployed()
The Safe is predictably, not yet deployed.
Following this guide, I see that the next step is to do some transactions.
However, I don't need any other trasnaction (other than the deployment of the Safe) to be sponsored.
I did a workaround for now and did a no-op transaction, like this:
const noOpTransaction = {
    to: safeAddress,
    value: '0',
    data: '0x', 
};

const safeOperation = await safe4337Pack.createTransaction({ transactions: [noOpTransaction] })

const signedSafeOperation = await safe4337Pack.signSafeOperation(safeOperation)

const userOperationHash = await safe4337Pack.executeTransaction({
    executable: signedSafeOperation
})

And then I see that the Safe is actually deployed.
However, is there a way of not doing any other transaction?
To actually be able to deploy and sponsored the Safe without my workaround?
All the best!
UPDATE
I did this trick and it works.
However, I am facing an issue. Since I am doing a noOpTransaction, signing and executing that transaction, if the threshold of my safe is larger than 1, the operation will ,expectedly, not succeed. I would need to retrieve the other signature for the threshold to be met and for the Safe to be actually deployed (and that's not feasible for our use case)
As a reminder, what I am looking for is a way of sponsoring the deployment of a Safe... I found this noOpTransaction workaround but it has this limitation.
I found that there is a .createSafeDeploymentTransaction() method declared in the Safe class. I don't know if that can be anther workaround or what can I do in order to be able to sponsor the deployment of a Safe.
Any help is very much appreciated!

As of now there's no alternative way to deploy a Safe using the 4337Pack. It may seem surprising but since it is not possible to sponsor a Safe deployment using the other Kits from Safe{Core} SDK, the 4337Pack was designed with precisely this in mind. The caveat being that we need to pass a transaction to deploy it. Your approach seems good though - if you really need one you can always create a dummy one so it does not impact the deployment costs too negatively.
Hope it answered your question; Best, Louis

Hi Louise! Thank you very much for you always very complete answers. I am running into an issue with the threshold and can't find a workaround. I have updated the question. Thanks and all the best!

Thank you for your kind words  One solution would be to first deploy the Safe with a threshold of 1, and then change the threshold with a new transaction (only after the Safe has been deployed). Would that work for you? Best, Louis

Thanks for your answer!
That wouldn't work for my use case. We have an onboarding flow that we sponsor the Safe creation using Pimlico with the threshold set at least at 2. We don't want to create another transaction for updating it.
Do you see any other solutions? At the end, what we are aiming for, is to sponsor the Safe creation using the Safe4337 Pack (the noOpTransaction was just a workaround).

Sponsoring deployment transactions with Pimlico will only work with a threshold set of 1 (sometimes referred to as a "single-signer safe"; so a possible workaround could be to keep this threshold at 1, and then execute a transaction to change the threshold to 2 (instead of sending a no-op). Do you think this could work in your case? The Safe would have a threshold of 1 only for a few seconds, the time for it to be correctly deployed and configured. Please let me know. Best, Louis

Hi dear Louis!
I made a follow up question on this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/166450/error-safe-is-not-yet-deployed
Thanks!!

Thank you! just replied there. Feel free to mark this question (and/or the one there) solved. Thanks in advance! Best, Louis

Hey! Thank you! Just one more question—will it be possible in the near future to sponsor a Safe via Pimlico with a threshold larger than 1? Is this feature planned for release soon?
