Error: Safe is not yet deployed
Follow up question on Sponsoring the deployment of a Safe without the need to create another transaction
I am trying to change the threshold of a recently created Safe. The function I provide, runs after I check that the Safe is deployed by doing something like the following check.
Note that I am using the safe4337Pack, since I want to sponsor that change threshold transaction (besides sponsoring the Safe creation done in a previous step)
while (!safeDeployed) {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 15000));
    safeDeployed = await safe4337Pack.protocolKit.isSafeDeployed();
    console.log("Safe deployed status:", safeDeployed);
}


console.log("Safe is deployed. Proceeding to change threshold...");

await changeThreshold(safe4337Pack, threshold)

The changeThreshold function looks like this
async function changeThreshold(safe4337Pack, threshold) {
  console.log("Creating threshold change transaction...")
  console.log("Is safe deployed?", await safe4337Pack.protocolKit.isSafeDeployed())
  console.log("Safe contract address", await safe4337Pack.protocolKit.getAddress())

  const thresholdTransactionUpdate = await safe4337Pack.protocolKit.createChangeThresholdTx(threshold)
  const safeOperationThreshold = await safe4337Pack.createTransaction({ transactions: [thresholdTransactionUpdate] })
  const signedSafeOperationThreshold = await safe4337Pack.signSafeOperation(safeOperationThreshold)
  const userOperationHashThreshold = await safe4337Pack.executeTransaction({
      executable: signedSafeOperationThreshold
});

  return userOperationHashThreshold 
}

The error I get when running this changeThreshold function is
Error: Safe is not deployed, from node_modules/@safe-global/protocol-kit/dist/src/managers/ownerManager.js:115:19)

It is weird to me, since by tracking down the code in OwnerManager.ts, I see that the error is raised if there is no SafeContract https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/blob/9b64da33bc55615349d527909d4b792e05bb9826/packages/protocol-kit/src/managers/ownerManager.ts#L134
However, in my changeThreshold function, I am doing a call to .getAddress(), that checks if the Safe has a contract! And it actually returns the SafeAddress
https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/blob/9b64da33bc55615349d527909d4b792e05bb9826/packages/protocol-kit/src/Safe.ts#L295C1-L296C1
There seems to be a discrepancy. I am quite sure that the Safe is actually deployed, because I can see it in the Safe UI and I can also see that when doing .isSafeDeployed() I get true
This is what I get in my terminal when running this piece of code.
Safe deployed status: true
Safe is deployed. Proceeding to change threshold...
Creating threshold change transaction...
Is safe deployed? true
Safe contract address 0x02___REST_OF_ADDRESS
/node_modules/@safe-global/protocol-kit/dist/src/managers/ownerManager.js:115
            throw new Error('Safe is not deployed');

Any help is very much appreciated!
UPDATE
Based on a recomendation on the Discord server, I added some code to review with a block explorer to check if the Safe has actually been deployed to the blockchain or not.
What I noticed is that actually, even if the .isSafeDeployed(), it doesn't mean that the Safe is actually deployed to the blockchain.
Is it that it exists in the Transaction Service and not in the blockchain per se?
Are there any options for making this work?
What I am trying to do is to sponsor the deployment of a Safe using Pimlico with a threshold larger than 1. I am fist deploying it with threshold set to 1 and then I want to execute the transaction to change the threshold right away!
TIA!

Thank you for following up! This is indeed a bug; the protocol kit should update after deployment, but it is not the case.
An issue has been opened here to solve the problem, and you will be able to follow the progress on that there.
In the meantime, you can work around the issue by adding this line right after the console.logs in your changeThreshold function:
const updated = await safe4337Pack.protocolKit.connect({
    safeAddress: <NEWLY_DEPLOYED_SAFE_ADDRESS>
    signer: <THE_SAME_SIGNER_PREVIOUSLY_USED>
});

... and use updated instead of safe4337Pack in the following lines.
Hope this helps! Best, Louis
P.S: Feel free to mark the question as solved if your problem has been addressed.

Hi Louis!
Thanks for your answer. Really appreciate all the help. Just wondering if there's an estimated time for tackling this issue? Thanks in advance and all the best!

Hi! Thank you  Yes, it has been included in a sprint, feel free to check again in a few weeks! I cannot give you exact dates unfortunately.

Thank you Louis!! All the best and thanks for all the work you guys do! All the best !
